# TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following:

```
    <p *ngIf="model.something.satisfy"> Yes </p>
    <p *ngIf="!model.something.satisfy"> {{model.something.comments}} </p>
```

The error appears in the second line "TypeError: Cannot read property 'satisfy' of undefined "

I've tried:

```
- *ngIf="!model.something?.satisfy  
- <div class="col-sm-10 offset-1" *ngIf="model.something>
```

Comment: Try using != in the second line instead of !model.

Comment: nope, it doesn't work

Comment: It's weird that is does not cause an error for the line line if it does for the 2nd one. Try `!(model.something)?.satisfy` or `!((model.something)?.satisfy)`

Comment: `model.something` is undefined. Show the component code .

Comment: check his link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ropvkv and update the scenario

Comment: First check what your are getting in model and put the structure here to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<p *ngIf="model.something && model.something.satisfy"> 
   Yes 
</p>
<p *ngIf="! (model.something && model.something.satisfy)"> 
  {{model.something.comments}} 
</p>
```

Use this code. Here firstly we are checking if model.something is present, then only we are accessing model.something.satisfy.